# Dependent observations in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is there an option such as mixed models for neural networks in which dependent observations can be grouped and compared to each other? As an example say we have a questionnaire with 3500 observations but these observations only come from 300 people having answered the questionnaire.

Or is independence of observations not a requirement for NN? (I'm new to them).